# how to perform node deletion (Inorder traversal)on a non-sorted binary tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am creating a remove() method for a binary tree that is not sorted. The binary tree is created from taking in data from a text file in order of precedence. So far I have code for when the node to be deleted is a left leaf node but the code is not actually doing any removal. My code for the main class:

```
package binarytree_manita;


public class BinaryTree {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Welcome to the program.");
        System.out.println("In this program, you can perform various operations on a binary tree");
        System.out.println("");

        // create an instance of PrintMenu class 
        UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface();
        userInterface.InitializeTree();
        userInterface.PrintMenu();
    }
    
}
```

My code for UserInterface class:

```
package binarytree;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class UserInterface {
    private BT binaryTree = new BT();
    public void InitializeTree(){
        //load tree elements from a file
        String fileName = "Numbers.txt";
        File inFile = new File(fileName);
       
        try
        {
           Scanner inScan = new Scanner(inFile);
           
           while(inScan.hasNext())
           {
               int number = inScan.nextInt();
                getBinaryTree().insert(number);
           }
        }
        
        //Error message if file don't exist or file connection isn't right
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
           String err_mess = "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+
                             "Trouble reading data from: "+fileName+"\n"+
                             "This Programing is ending!"+
                             "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
           System.err.print(err_mess);
           System.exit(0);
       }
        //insert tree elements in order of appearence
        
    }
    
    public void PrintMenu(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        int option = 0;
        while(option != 6){
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Menu Please enter an option given bellow: ");
            System.out.println("Option     Operation Completed");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println("1       Insert");
            System.out.println("2       Remove");
            System.out.println("3       Search");
            System.out.println("4       Find Height");
            System.out.println("5       Print Elements");
            System.out.println("6       Quit");
            
            option = input.nextInt();
            
            switch(option){
                        
                        case 1:
                            //add code for Insert
                            
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            //add code for Remove
                            System.out.println("Enter the integer you want to remove:");
                            int remove = input.nextInt();
                            getBinaryTree().remove(remove);
                            
                            System.out.println(
                            "\nInorder traversal of updated binary tree is ");
                            getBinaryTree().printTree();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            //add code for Search
                            System.out.println("Enter the integer you want to search for:");
                            int search = input.nextInt();
                            getBinaryTree().search(search);
                        case 4:
                            //add code for Find Height
                        case 5:
                            //add code for Print Elements
                            System.out.println(
                            "\nInorder traversal of binary tree is ");
                            getBinaryTree().printTree();
                        case 6:
                            //add code for Quit
                            System.out.println("Thank you for using our program.");
                            System.exit(0);
                            break;
                            
                        //Error message if user inputs anything other than 1-5 
                        default:
                            System.out.println(option + " is not a correct choice.\n"
                                               + "please enter another option. \n");
                            break;
            }
        }
    }

    
    public BT getBinaryTree() {
        return binaryTree;
    }
    
    
}
```

My code for BTNode class:

```
package binarytree;


public class BTNode {
    
    BTNode left, right;
    int data;
    
    public BTNode(){
        
        left = null;
        right = null;
        data = 0;
    }
    
    public BTNode(int n){
        
        left = null;
        right = null;
        data = n;
    }
    
    //sets a reference to the left child’s location
    public void setLeft(BTNode n){
        
        left = n;
    }
    
    //sets a reference to the right child’s location
    public void setRight(BTNode n){
        
        left = n;
    }
    
    //returns the location of the left child
    public BTNode getLeft(){
        
        return left;
    }
    //returns the location of the right child
    public BTNode getRight(){
        
        return right;
    }
    
    //initializes/updates the data for the node
    public void setData(int d){
        data = d;
    }
    //returns the data in the node but does not remove it
    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

My code for BT class:

```
package binarytree;


public class BT {
    
    private BTNode root;
    
    //Tree constructor that initializes the root node to null
    public BT(){
        root = null;
    }
    
    // isEmpty() - Function to check if tree is empty
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if (root == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    //2 insert methods, one to begin the insert and another to recurse the tree
    //insert data
    public void insert (int data){
        
        root = insert(root, data);
    }
    
    //insert data recursively
    private BTNode insert (BTNode node, int data){
        
        if (node == null)
            node = new BTNode(data);
        
        else{
            if (node.getRight() == null){
                node.right = insert(node.right, data);
                //System.out.println("Right");
            }
            else{
                node.left = insert(node.left, data);
                //System.out.println("Left");
            }
        }
        
        return node;
    }

    //2 count methods, one to begin the count and another to recurse the tree
    //count the number of nodes
    public int countNodes(){
        return countNodes(root);
    }
    
    //count the number of nodes recursively
    private int countNodes(BTNode r){
        
        if (r == null)
            return 0;
        else{
            int l = 1;
            l += countNodes(r.getLeft());
            l += countNodes(r.getRight());
            return l;
        }
    }
    
    //2 search methods, one to begin the search and another to recurse the tree
    //search for an element
    public boolean search(int val){
        return search(root, val);
    }
    
    //search for an element recursively
    private boolean search(BTNode r, int val){
        
        if (r.getData() == val){
            System.out.println("found");
            return true;
        }
        if (r.getLeft() != null){
            if(search(r.getLeft(), val))
                System.out.println("found");
                return true;
        }
        if (r.getRight() != null){
            if(search(r.getRight(), val))
                System.out.println("found");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    //remove a given elemment
    public boolean remove(int val){
        return remove (root, val);
    }
    
    //search for an element recursively
    //Returns true if removed, returns false if cannot remove.
    private boolean remove(BTNode r, int val){
        //if binary tree is empty
        if (root == null){
            return false;
        }
        if (r.getData() == val){         //val to be deleted is root node
            //delete root
            r = null;
            return true;
        }
        if (r.getLeft() != null){
            BTNode parent = r;
            if(remove(r.getLeft(), val))      //val to be deleted is a left node
                
                //case 1 - if node to be deleted has 0 left child (left leaf node)
                if (r.getLeft() == null ){
                    parent.setLeft(null);
                    return true;
                }
                
                //case 2 - if node to be deleted has left child (internal node)
                
        }
        if (r.getRight() != null){
            if(remove(r.getRight(), val))
                //case 1: right leaf node
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public void printTree() { 
        printTree(root); 
    }

    private void printTree(BTNode r){
        
        if (r == null){
            System.out.println("The binary tree is empty.");
        }
        if (r.getLeft() != null){
            printTree(r.left);
            System.out.print(r.data + " ");
        }
        if (r.getLeft() == null){
            System.out.print(r.data + " ");
        }
        if (r.getRight() != null){
            printTree(r.right);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You still have some work to do there. But the main problem is that `r = null` does not remove the node. It merely changes a variable, but not the tree. As providing the whole deletion code is out of scope (too broad), you would need to bring down your question to just deal with one case only. Don't expect the full deletion code.

Comment: I think I have the algorithm for the whole deletion code figured out, so can I ask you how can I fix the " r = null " issue? And possibly what am I doing wrong in  //case 1 - if node to be deleted has 0 left child (left leaf node) ? Thank you.

Comment: The big problem is the remove does not change the structure.  It only return true if the item to be removed in in the tree.  I have written a solution here:  https://onlinegdb.com/_-TeNqQUN